# SQL Query to LINQ conversion

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I want to convert my SQL Server's query to LINQ. The query is:

```
DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = '[24/03/2012],[23/03/2012],[22/03/2012]'
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = N'SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT ''Total Processed'' as [Total Processed], CONVERT(VARCHAR,datestatuschanged,103) AS ''DATE'',applicationid
            FROM    dbo.vwProductivityRpt
            where status=''Open'') p
PIVOT
(
count(applicationid) FOR DATE IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt' 

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: First question is, why?  You're using SQL-specific functionality such as `CONVERT(` and `PIVOT` which will be difficult to replicate in LINQ.  Is your business process fundamentally broken in some way that requires LINQ instead of SQL?

Comment: Could you give us an example result of your query and maybe what data are you selecting from?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160817/pivot-in-c-sharp-entity-framework-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ requires that all your columns are statically named. This means you need to construct a query expression using reflection which is a nasty type of work.

In a way, reflection in .NET does the same thing you are doing with string concatenation in SQL - you dynamically create a query which must have statically named columns.

I think you are better off staying with SQL for this particular task.